# From ajax success function not able to return value

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using the ajax to fetch data from server.

```
function getData(){
     $.ajax({
           ......,
           success: function(resp){
               console.log(resp);
               return resp;
           }

    });
}
```

But when I try

```
var fetchedData = getData();
```

Then **fetchData** is empty.

But when I checked console then there is data.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Comment: first check you got any response for your request

Comment: to check for response, if you're using firebug or chrome development tools, just right click your console window and choose Log XMLHTTPresults. You will see if your page returns a result

Comment: @Mr.G He's using the success callback.  His problem is that he's trying to run asynchronous code in a synchronous manner, hence my comment above, with a link that explains this.

Comment: I think you should use synchronous request although its very bad idea!!!

Comment: I have checked the link provide by the **Archer** this is answer to my question. Thanks **Archer**

Comment: Please check the auto suggestions comes while posting the question. You may get any one question which is similar with your question and may it solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [callback function](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/).

```
function getData(callback){

     $.ajax({
           ......,
           success: function(resp){
               callback(resp);
           }

    });


}

function getResult(data)
{
 console.log(data);

}
```

**To call this-**

```
getData(getResult);
```

**Edit-**
Also a better answer is available here-[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: What is the relation between data and resp?

Comment: Your data variable is a local variable with resp passed onto it. i.e. They are the same value.

Comment: `return data;` makes it a little confusing but it's refreshing to see that someone who's posting an answer at least knows what asynchronous and callback means

Comment: The code is edited to remove the return statement. And @Archer as with all good things,the only way to learn is by failing.

Comment: upvoted this to counter some idiotic downvotes